# Selenium unable to locate xpath however the xpath is there in the browser

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Im not sure if that was quite the best title but Im not sure how else to describe it, I am trying to use selenium to automate 2fa on a website so all I need to do is anwser the phone call and the script will take care of the rest however the button I am trying to get selenium to click keeps showing up as unable to locate even though its always in the same place and never changes here is my code in python

```
callMe = driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="auth_methods"]/fieldset/div[2]/button')
callMe.click()
sleep(25)
```

this is one of three buttons that all have the same element information besides the xpaths here are all 3 button elements I am trying to grab the second one

```
<button tabindex="2" type="submit" class="positive auth-button"><!-- -->Send Me a Push </button>
<button tabindex="2" type="submit" class="positive auth-button"><!-- -->Call Me </button>
<button tabindex="2" type="submit" class="positive auth-button"><!-- -->Text Me </button>
```

I am not sure how else I can locate the second button besides using the xpath but that is not working and I dont know if I can or how I can search for the button based off the text that is inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `By` ?

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

callMe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="auth_methods"]/fieldset/div[2]/button')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using By.cssselector, get the css selector of the main body html for the button you want.

```
callMe = driver.find_element(By.css_selector, 'selectorofbodyhtml')
callme.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below xpath

```
//button[starts-with(text(),'Call Me')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired element <kbd>Call Me</kbd> is a dynamic element, so to click on it you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH* and *`contains()`*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(., 'Call Me')]"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *`starts-with()`*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[starts-with(., 'Call Me')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```